# What is the correct method to compare time series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have daily mean temperature for 20 years for 5 different locations. How can I compare the time series statistically?
The locations are all in UK so the seasonality is the same.
I want to see if the series have any differences. In the best case to see if they are statistically different with some test.

Comment: What do you mean by *compare statistically*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added more info